# Did the write xlsx function in R get updated and how do I use it now?

Tags: r, xlsx

I have an old code that uses the command

```
write.xlsx(tablename, "file.xlsx", asTable=FALSE, row.names=TRUE)
```

A few months ago, that would write the table to an Excel file with row names, and overwrite when I reran it. Now it writes only one cell in the Excel file and doesn't overwrite.

Comment: Are you using `openxlsx::write.xlsx`? That function's first-three args (your `tablename`, `"file.xlsx"`, and `asTable=FALSE`) have not changed in at least 7 years, so that's not likely an issue. (*However*, I am mildly curious why a variable named `tablename` (emphasis on "name") would contain a `data.frame`, following some semblance of variable naming conventions. Are you sure `tablename` is a `data.frame`? I'm guessing this is just a stackoverflow-ism, simplifying the question ... but just to make sure, what do `class(tablename)` and `dim(tablename)` return? )

Comment: Sorry, that was a very misleading way for me to write my sample code. "tablename" is supposed to represent a dataframe (it's a dataframe in my real code). The dimensions are 294x4. And yes, this is from the openxlsx package.

Comment: Is there a way to make this question reproducible? Can you reproduce it with (say) `tablename[1:3,1:3]` and still have it fill only one cell? If so, please add `dput(tablename[1:3,1:3])` to your question and let us "play" with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure when it got updated, but the *overwrite* parameter on `write.xlsx` now defaults to `FALSE`.  So you will need to set it to `TRUE` to overwrite an existing file.

```
write.xlsx(tablename, "c:\\temp\\file.xlsx", asTable=FALSE, row.names=TRUE, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Concerning the writing of only one cell, I'm suspicious of your data.  The function is working normally with test data.